# Connecting a USB Thermal Printer in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, thermal-printer

I'm running Windows 10, my Laravel app runs inside `vagrant/laravel` homestead using virtual box.

I need to connect a printer to print out receipts using this package [ESCPOS-PHP](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) I tried this using XAMPP it works, but I don't know to make it work when my application is running inside `vagrant/laravel` homestead

Comment: Try, fail, describe (c/p) error message. What happens when you try the same way as you would in XAMPP, what is in log, any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should warn you that the laravel homestead environment is meant only for development and not production. However if you want to connect any device to the vagrant box you can opt for enabling the gui configuration adding

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
end
```

at the end of the file named `Vagrantfile`. This option will have as a result to start Homestead in a VirtualBox window allowing you to attach usb devices by right clicking on the USB connector icon at the lower right of the window.

Bear in mind that VirtualBox has support only for USB 1.1 if you haven't installed the VirtualBox Extension Pack. Downloading the Extension Pack and installing it enables USB2.x and 3.x support.

Make sure that the printer is supported in Linux as making the connection is only part of the problem. The [Open Printing](https://www.openprinting.org/printers) site has support status for most printers.

Comment: For example, the EPSON printer presented in `Open Printing` does not have a thermal printer (model number starting with `TM-`). Even if it's a good description of the feature, it's likely that this answer doesn't really address the question.

Comment: True although Open Printing doesn't have all models. I would look around with a search engine using the model number as keyword to be sure.